# MySQL - count users for each day and count them all

Tags: mysql, datetime, aggregate-functions

Is it possible to count new users for each day and count all users in the table in the same query? 
This query is working (it is counting user per day), I just need to add part where it is counting all users.

```
SELECT COUNT(iduser) as newUsers, add_date
FROM cs_user
GROUP BY DAY(add_date)
```

Example I need:

```
 newUsers   add_date    
1   2016-05-05 17:33:49
5   2016-03-10 16:44:33
2   2016-04-15 19:50:42
5   2016-05-16 18:46:52
6   2016-04-18 15:01:34
1   2016-03-21 23:50:40
2   2016-03-22 18:22:48
3   2016-03-23 22:02:45
2   2016-03-25 16:38:56
15  2016-04-27 18:05:43
3   2016-04-29 04:54:05
23  2016-03-30 17:27:26
```

I need a new row where it should writhe the number of all users.

Comment: How do you differentiate `new user` and `old user`? Also add your expected output.

Comment: This is time based query - you select day since you want to track new users (I will insert WHERE condition later, just need to count all users first).

Comment: Yes, it is possible, using conditional counting (condition is placed within the count() or sum() function).

Comment: It's still unclear to me. Please add your expected output based on some sample data. That might do.

Comment: WITH ROLLUP might be able to achieve that already, http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-modifiers.html

Comment: In select Instead of `add_date` use `DAY(add_date)` this may resolve your problem

Comment: Then `rollup` it is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `WITH ROLLUP` option to `GROUP BY`. This will add an extra row to the result set that contains the overall `COUNT()`.

By the way, [the `DATE()` function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date) produces the date from a `DATETIME` item, such as your `add_date` column. [The `DAY()` function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_day) produces the day of the month. You should decide which one you need.

I think this query will do what you want.

```
SELECT COUNT(iduser) as newUsers, DATE(add_date) day
  FROM cs_user
 GROUP BY DATE(add_date) WITH ROLLUP
```

Comment: This is what I wanted :). Thanks a lot for the help and extra explanation.

Answer (score 2):

you can use union:

```
SELECT COUNT(iduser) as newUsers, add_date
FROM cs_user
GROUP BY DAY(add_date)

UNION ALL
SELECT   COUNT(iduser) as newUsers, NOW()
FROM cs_user
```